# retrieve post details in loop

Tags: post-status

I have written a function to loop through the users posts, and im trying to display each of the posts by their status, with a different message for each status group.

for some reason - get_post_status doesnt work, nor do any of the other hooks. can anyone help? ive even tried to temporarily shorten the function and just echo out the variables to see what theyre doing and its just blank.

```
function user_item($type, $tax, $term_name, $term_id) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) return;  
    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => $type,
        'author'                => get_current_user_id(),
        //'post_status'                 => $status,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy'      => $tax,
            'field'         => $term_name,
            'terms'         => $term_id,
            'include_children'  => false
            )
        )
    );
        
        $jobs = get_posts( $args );
        
            foreach($jobs as $job){
                $jobid = get_the_ID($job);
                $stat =  get_post_status($jobid);
                $items = $job->post_title;
                ?>
                
                <div> <?php echo ($jobid)?></div>;
                <div> <?php echo ($stat)?></div>;
                <div> <?php echo ($items)?></div>;

<?php
            
                    
            }


function fd1(){
    echo user_item('post type name','post taxonomy name','taxonomy term name','taxonomy term id', 'draft');
    }

    add_shortcode( 'fd1_list', 'fd1' );
```

below is the full code - however  the following loop works when i write it this way - but only for the 'publish' post status.

```
function user_item($type, $tax, $term_name, $term_id, $status) {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) return;  
    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => $type,
        'author'                => get_current_user_id(),
        'post_status'           => $status, //need to define the status because if left blank it defaults to only publish status
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
            'taxonomy'      => $tax,
            'field'         => $term_name,
            'terms'         => $term_id,
            'include_children'  => false
            )
        )
    );
        
        $jobs = get_posts( $args );
        
            foreach($jobs as $job){
                $stat =  get_post_status($job->ID);
                $items = $job->post_title;
                
                //echo $items, ' - ', $stat;
                
                    if ($stat === 'publish'){?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($job ->ID);?>">
                        <div><?php echo $items, ' - ', $status ?></div>
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <?php
                    }
                    
                    elseif ($stat === 'draft'){?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($job ->ID);?>">
                        <div><?php echo $items, ' - ', $status ?></div>
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <?php
                    }
                
                    elseif ($stat === 'pending'){?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($job ->ID);?>">
                        <div><?php echo $items, ' - ', $status ?></div>
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <?php
                    }
                
                    elseif ($stat === 'archived'){?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($job ->ID);?>">
                        <div><?php echo $items, ' - ', $status ?></div>
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <?php
                    }
                
                    else {?>
                        <a href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($job ->ID);?>">
                        <div><?php echo $items, ' - ', $status ?></div>
                        </a>
                        <br>
                        <?php
                    }
                
            }
```

Comment: `if ($status = 'publish')`, `elseif ($status = 'draft')` and `elseif ($status = 'draft')` - that `=` should be `==` or `===` ..

Comment: Sorry, in my previous comment, the other "draft" was a typo and I actually meant "pending".. anyway, I agreed with the current answer and additionally, keep in mind that a shortcode (function) should *not* echo anything and instead, *return* the output. Also, the [`field` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/__construct/) in a tax query clause should be a database field name like `term_id` or `slug`, and not the name of a term like "My Category".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, change those `=` to `===` as [mentioned by @sally-cj](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/388088/retrieve-post-details-in-loop/388094#comment563106_388088) in the comment.

On top of that, you're saving the status as a variable called `$stat` and are then checking it as `$status`. So you might want to change `$stat = get_post_status($job->ID);` into `$status =  get_post_status($job->ID);`.

Or better: the `$job` is already populated with a field called `post_status`, so use `$post->post_status`.

Comment: thanks both of your for the replies! i think ive got what you meant. Ive adjusted the code in the thread. it does work. unless theres another change you think i need to make? (im not a dev so this is pretty much the limit of my current skillset)

Comment: If it works, there is nothing to fix anymore ;-) Glad I could help you